# System.TypeLoadException when try to create instance of C++ COM object inside custom AppDomain

Tags: c#, c++, com, appdomain

I'm trying to load dynamically a COM object inside a custom AppDomain.

So I did this code which is working with C# COM object but not working with C++ COM object.

```
Type addinComType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid.Parse(guid));
string basePath = Directory.GetParent(addinComType.Assembly.Location).FullName;
string dllName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(addinComType.Assembly.Location);
string completePath = addinComType.Assembly.Location;
string typeName = addinComType.Name;


AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup()
{
    ApplicationBase = basePath,
    ApplicationName = dllName,
    ConfigurationFile = dllName + ".dll.config",
    PrivateBinPath = $"{basePath};{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase}"
};

AppDomain customDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(guid, null, setup);
ObjectHandle objectHandleFromCustomDomain = customDomain.CreateComInstanceFrom(completePath, typeName); //Thrown exception
object addinObjectFromCustomDomain = objectHandleFromCustomDomain.Unwrap();
MethodInfo myAddinMethodFromCustomDomain = addinObjectFromCustomDomain.GetType().GetMethod("connectToAPI");
myAddinMethodFromCustomDomain.Invoke(addinObjectFromCustomDomain, new object[] { null });
```

This code generate

```
System.TypeLoadException: Impossible to load type '__ComObject' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
à System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
à System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
à System.Activator.CreateComInstanceFrom(String assemblyName, String typeName, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm)
à System.AppDomain.CreateComInstanceFrom(String assemblyName, String typeName)
à System.AppDomain.CreateComInstanceFrom(String assemblyName, String typeName)
à ConsoleApp1.AddinLoader.LoadAddin(String guid) dans C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\AddinLoader.cs:ligne 113
```

- C# app and my C++ COM object are build in X64 mode.
- Working if I create instance in the default domain like `((API.AddIn)Activator.CreateInstance(addinComType)).connectToAPI(null)`

So I don't know where this problem is come from.

In C# my COM object inherit from [MarshalByRefObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/api/system.marshalbyrefobject?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) maybe I need something like that for C++ COM object ?

So if you have any idea,
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: That is an awfully wonky exception, I can't think of many flavors of mscorlib.dll that doesn't have `__ComObject`.  Other than a reference assembly, perhaps.  Only way to get ahead is to use Fuslogvw.exe, start it elevated and configure it to log all binds, it shows where mscorlib.dll came from.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your answer. I  have 3 entries related to my exe (other logs are related to MSBuild or IntelliTrace). One of these entry is about mscorlib (another about mscorlib.resource) and says: `JRN : An Assembly was found in the GAC` (full log : https://pastebin.com/jwV1Se9j)

Comment: Translating what you see is not a good idea, we are not afraid of a little French.  But it otherwise offers no good explanation.  Try another machine.

Comment: @HansPassant I have tried on another dev computer, and same error. (I translate the log for helping people who doesn't understand french ;) )

Comment: I suppose you'll have to conclude that using an AppDomain to isolate a COM server is not a good idea.  There is no point to it at all anyway, the Unwrap() call screws the pooch with the interop assembly getting loaded in the primary domain as well.  And above all, appdomains don't provide any isolation whatsoever to native code.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that app domain doesn't work with native code.... So I tried to do something stupid..... Where did you find this information ?